# using linux system call "read" to read one character of a file

Tags: linux, call, system, nasm

So I'm trying to read through a file one character at a time using the linux system call read with nasm, but no matter what I specify my count to be, it reads the entire file. 
I know read takes 3 parameters, the first is the file descriptor, the second is the buffer where the data is being written to, and the third is the number of bytes to be read. I have the following. I've omitted a lot of the code because this is just part of a much larger project

```
 section .data 
 bufsize: db 1 

 section .bss
 buf  resb 256

 ; read the file
    mov     eax,  3         ; read(
    mov     ebx,  [file_pointer]       ;   file_descriptor,
    mov     ecx,  buf       ;   *buf,
    mov     edx,  bufsize   ;   *bufsize
    int     80h             ; );

 ; write to STDOUT
    mov     edx, eax        ; move number of bytes read into edx
    mov     eax, 4          ; system call for write
    mov     ebx, 1          ; STDOUT file descriptor
                            ; ecx is already set up. its the buffer
    int     80h             ; call kernel
```

However when I use the system call to write what's in buf, it prints out the entire file, not just the first character. I know my file pointer is correct. I feel like I must be declaring my bufsize wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From [the manpage for `read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html):

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

As you can see, the third parameter is the number of bytes to read, not a pointer to the number of bytes to read.

So this line in your code:

```
mov     edx,  bufsize   ;   *bufsize
```

should be:

```
mov     edx,  [bufsize]   ;   bufsize
```

and `bufSize` should be declared as:

```
bufsize: dd 1
```

(or you could just do `mov edx,1`)

Comment: If you're going to change the declaration of `bufsize`, change it to `bufsize equ 1`.   (And optionally declare the buffer as `buf: resb bufsize`).  If you're going to change the `mov edx, bufsize` into a load, change it to a byte load (`movzx edx, byte [bufsize]`.)